# EntryPointNotFoundException while selfhosting WebAPI using OWIN

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I am trying to selfthost web API using OWIN by following the below link

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

But, during the execution of this below line

```cs
using (WebApp.Start<SelfHostStartup>(url: baseAddress))
```

I am getting **EntryPointNotFoundException** as MyNamespace.SelfHostStartup was not found in assembly.

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```cs
public class SelfHostStartup
{
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Loads external library's (that contain the web api controllers) into the web api self host system
        var assemblyResolver = new SelfHostAssemblyResolver();
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), assemblyResolver);

        // Creates the IoC Container & mounts to Web API
        config.DependencyResolver =
            new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(Framework.Infastructure.Dependency.AutofacContainer.Container);

        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new MyNamespace.ApiExceptionLogger(Framework.Infastructure.Dependency.AutofacContainer.Resolve<ILogger>()));
        // Configures Web API Controller Routing
        RouteConfig(config);

        config.EnsureInitialized();
        // Tells OWIN self host to use this configuration
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configuration of the Routing for the Web API Controllers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config"></param>
    private void RouteConfig(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
#if DEBUG
        //Enabling Cors Globally
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:60279", "*", "*"));
#else
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
#endif
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Core",
            routeTemplate: "api/core/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Domain",
            routeTemplate: "api/domain/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Domain1",
           routeTemplate: "api/domain/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: How's your entry point defined? What does your `SelfHostStartup` class look like? Please provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the response rdoubleui, i have edited the post with SelfHostStartup class definition.

Comment: Have you found a solution?